# How to test rollback is working as expected?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop

I am trying to write an integration/unit test where an exception is applied to a DAO after a save has been performed - in order to validate the rollback behaviour.  My thoughts were to create a Spring AOP aspect - and apply @AfterReturning advice to the 'save' method on the DAO.

The DAO is already proxied via @Transactional advice.

Does this seem like the right way to go ?

So far I'm trying to use a Spring ProxyFactory - to proxy the DAO in the unit test.

E.g.

```
 ProxyFactory pf = new ProxyFactory(new MyFaultInjectingAspect());
 pf.setTarget(myDao);
 MyDao proxiedDao = (BookmarkDao) pf.getProxy();
```

Thank you.

FYI:  relates to this [Is it ok to use DataSourceTransactionManager for ORM persistence instead of HibernateTransactionManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8122409/366073)

Comment: Do you have a mechanism for the transaction to fail and therefore cause the rollback? Do you have a way for your test to set up this failure?

Comment: The question relates to how to create that mechanism.  I'm considering using an aspect to inject an exception which causes the failure.

Answer (score 1):

From your DB side you can issue a lock by using select for update.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

And try to commit with your application, you should see a transaction rolled back exception, but with different reason.

updated link.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is other approach without any AOP that *really* checks that nothing is written in the DB:

If you have a test that verifies (if there is no exception) that the transaction is commited, and the entity is written to the DB, then you only need simple second test.

In this test you must do the same but with exception. And then you must only verify that noting is written to the DB. So you do not need the AOP Stuff, and your test becomes more meaningful because it test in the end what you really want. (*I hopefully understand it right, that role back is only the technique to prohibit the database change.*)

Comment: +1. Thanks for the suggestion. I am actually trying to confirm rollback *is* working.  But maybe the test is too convoluted.  I may try a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to do something similar to this:

[How to rollback a database transaction when testing services with Spring in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166983/rollback-transaction-when-testing-service-with-spring-hibernate-junit#4167166)

Comment: Not really. This provides the mechanism to auto rollback at the end of each test. Not the mechanism to test that the rollback was done by the code under test.